# Help with Accessing Files from a Network Drive

Tags: mount

I am trying to access files from a network drive and don't know how to write the file path.

I am trying to get an application to open files from a network drive, but keep receiving the error: WARNING: /mnt/network drive/file path/... does not exist.

I tried seeing if I can even access the folder I need using "cd /" by "ls" the "mounted on pathways" displayed when using "df" and could not find the network drive needed. This is my first time working in a terminal and I don't know where to go from here.

more details: The hardware is four Synology NAS (Network Attached Storage) servers. The  NAS units each have volumes on them; the volumes share the total space on each NAS. I mounted them onto my file system for access. I mounted it onto my Windows 11 laptop remotely by connecting to the lab's VPN, selecting My computer > Map network drive, and typing in the server's address. I can access the files fine through files explorer (when connected to the lab's VPN).  The network is administered by the research lab I am part of and above are the instructions they gave me to connect.

Comment: We need more details... First, can you tell us what kind of network share is this? Is it NFS, Samba, CIFS? Who administers the network storage? Have you asked them how to connect? Can you even connect to that device? Is the network storage drive mounted on your computer? You should also be aware that you can not use spaces when typing paths in your terminal. Spaces in file names and directories are cumbersome to work with in the terminal, so it's wise to avoid using spaces in filenames and directories. However you can still type them using single quotes `'` or by escaping with a backslash